# IExpress command line without using .SED file

Tags: powershell, command-line, iexpress

Can I create installation (msi) package using IExpress in post build event but without using .SED file?

And if SED file is required then how to change TargetName and SourceFile path from command line?

I have created package but due to paths in SED file, it is not working for Automation build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IExpress doesn’t generate MSI files, it generates executables and CAB files only.

SED files are required. There’s no easy way to “override” the `TargetName` or `SourceFiles`. You’d have to write some kind of program to edit the SED file on-the-fly.

Comment: Shall I pass SourceFiles as relative path ?

Comment: You can do; it does work. By default, it uses full paths, though.

Comment: can you give me one example of that or syntax as I tried but it popup with error like path not found

Comment: You should really ask this in a separate question, not as a comment. Provide the syntax you are using and the error message you get back.

Comment: _There’s no easy way to “override” the TargetName or SourceFiles_ Actually there is, see: https://www.mdgx.com/INF_web/override.htm